# Share project between Windows Store Application And WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to create and "share" a class library project between an Windows Store Application and WCF Service project ?

I created Windows Store Application project and WCF Service project. Now, both projects should  refer a Class library project.

If I create a *regular* Class Library project, the WCF Service project can refer it.
But when I add the reference to the Windows Store Application Visual Studio 2012 says :

> Unable to add the reference to project XXX

So I decided to replace the *regular* Class Library project by a Class Library(Windows Store apps).
Now the Windows app project can refer the Class Library(Windows Store apps).
But when I add the reference to the WCF Service Visual Studio says :

> Unable to add the reference to project XXX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To share code between the two projects create a Portable Class Library (PCL) project and reference it in the two projects.

Make sure you choose the right .Net framework (for compatibility with WCF project).